# Microsoft.TestApi Object Comparison not recognising enum differences

Tags: c#, enums, comparison

I'm trying to compare 2 objects using [Microsoft.TestApi](https://testapi.codeplex.com/). The problem is that it is not picking up differences between enum values.

In the example below I would expect the test to pass because the enum values are different, however the TestApi comparison returns no mismatches.

How can I make it detect enum value differences?

**Code**

```
public class ObjectComparer
{
    public bool AreDifferent(Holiday h1, Holiday h2)
    {
        var comparer = new ObjectGraphComparer();

        var factory = new PublicPropertyObjectGraphFactory();
        var sourceGraph = factory.CreateObjectGraph(h1);
        var targetGraph = factory.CreateObjectGraph(h2);

        IEnumerable<ObjectComparisonMismatch> result;
        comparer.Compare(sourceGraph, targetGraph, out result);

        return result.Any();
    }
}

public class Holiday
{
    public Day Day { get; set; }
}

public enum Day
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldDetectDifferentEnumValues()
{
    var h1 = new Holiday {Day = Day.Monday};
    var h2 = new Holiday {Day = Day.Tuesday};
    var comparer = new ObjectComparer();

    var result = comparer.AreDifferent(h1, h2);

    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the source code of `Microsoft.TestApi` to see if `ObjectGraphComparer.compare()` looks at enum types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your code and made a small research in the source code. My friend you are out of luck, enums are not compared.

The code can be found on [codeplex](http://testapi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Releases/TestApi_v0.6/Sources/TestApiCore/Code/ObjectComparison/ObjectGraphComparer.cs), the relevant part is this

```
// compare primitives, strings, datatimes, guids
if (leftNode.ObjectType.IsPrimitive ||
            leftNode.ObjectType == typeof(string) ||
            leftNode.ObjectType == typeof(DateTime) ||
            leftNode.ObjectType == typeof(Guid))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to consider using the compare-net-objects library instead. https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects